# Como usar el post por url en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, querybuilder

Como puedo hacer que se envíen datos por POST usando el query builder de laravel o es imposible hacerlo, ya que según tengo entendido se debe usar el modelo y poner save, a continuación pongo un fragmento del código para que pueda explicarme mejor ya que lo que estoy mencionando es bastante abstracto a mi parecer.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Registros;

class RegistrosController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $reg = new Registros;
        $reg->nombre = $request->nombre;
        $reg->edad = $request->edad;
        $reg->save();
    }
}
```

Como lo puse anteriormente es como lo he trabajado y esto funciona para enviar una url así, http://localhost:8080/registros?nombre=juan&edad=20, y se registra el usuario en la base de datos pero quiero saber puedo hacer lo mismo pero con el query builder como lo muestro a continuación

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class RegistrosController extends Controller
{



    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $nombre = $request->nombre;
        $edad = $request->edad;
        DB::table('registros')->insert([
            'nombre'   => $nombre,
            'edad'  => $edad
        ]);
        
    }
}
```

Qué estoy haciendo mal?, o de plano no se puede realizar eso?

***edit***

este es mi api.php, que vienen siendo mis rutas y me equivoque , mando la información así http://localhost:8080/api/registros?nombre=juan&edad=20

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::resource('registros', 'RegistrosController');
```

Comment: ¿Podrías subir el código de tu fichero de rutas?

Comment: Lo que muestras se ve bien. ¿Te dá un error o por qué preguntas "que estoy haciendo mal"?

Comment: ya lo agregue @Youshiro

Comment: lo que digo que hago mal es para saber si tengo algún error de sintaxis, porque no se envía nada en el segundo caso @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 0):

puede que tu error este en la database, ya que implemente tu codigo como ejemplo y pude insertar datos con DB, lo que puedes hacer es un try catch dentro de tu función para saber el error que puedas tener.

```
try {
        $nombre = $request->nombre;
        $edad = $request->edad;
        DB::table('registros')->insert([
            'nombre'   => $nombre,
            'edad'  => $edad
        ]);
       
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $registros = $request->except('_token');
        registro::insert($registros);
    }
```

No sé si es a esto a lo que te refieres, pero es otro método para hacerlo. Guardas en una variable ($registros) todo lo que traes del formulario a excepción del token (csrf) y a continuación con el ORM logras insertarlo en la tabla.
registro es el modelo.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo idea absoluta del mundo de php pero si lo que quieres es mandar datos por la URL lo cual es un antipatron a no ser que los datos no sean importantes puedes mandarlos como query params

```
fetch("/add-dato?elDato=valor&otroDato")
```

O lo puedes hacer como request params

```
fetch("/user/enetoId/show-pic/12345678")
```

Y en el servidor necesitarías un enspoint tipo así

```
ComoSeaQueSeHaga.get("/user/:username/show-pic/:picId"...)
```

Supongo no se